# How to express the following if-else if-else statement in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to replicate the following requirements/code in Haskell

Pseudo-Code (the actual evaluations are much more complicated):

```
if (x == 1)
   doX()
else if (y == 1)
   doY()
else if (z == 1)
   doZ()
else
   doSomethingElse()
```

Right now I have this as WHEN statements for each, but that doesn't give me an ELSE, so I have

```
when (x == 1) $ do doX
when (y == 1) $ do doY
when (z == 1) $ do doZ
```

But then how do I manage my else?

Comment: Although @bheklilr's guards are more idiomatic for this, Haskell *does* have `if` ... `then` ... `else` ... expressions, so the pseudocode is only missing `then`s to be legal Haskell.  (But watch out for indentation if using `if then else` together with `do`.)

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen This is pretty much the reason why I chose guards for my examples, they avoid the nastiness of having to worry about indentation.

Comment: Not a serious answer: `[doX, doY, doZ] !! findIndex (==1) [x, y, z]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a good option for guards or a case statement.  You could do something like

```
myAction :: Monad m => Int -> Int -> Int -> m ()
myAction x y z
    | x == 1 = doX
    | y == 1 = doY
    | z == 1 = doZ
    | otherwise = doSomethingElse
```

Or you can use the [`MultiWayIf`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.8.1-rc1/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#multi-way-if) extension:

```
myAction :: Monad m => m ()
myAction = do
    x <- getX
    y <- getY
    z <- getZ
    if | x == 1 -> doX
       | y == 1 -> doY
       | z == 1 -> doZ
       | otherwise -> doSomethingElse
    -- continue doing more stuff in myAction as needed
```

Comment: You can even fake a multiway if with `case () of () | p1 -> e1; () | p2 -> e2 ...`